# Не могу получить данные о пользователе из база данных

Tags: php, mysql

В ответ на get запрос я хочу отдать пользователя с айдишником 1:

```
mysql_select_db("certificate");
$user = get_userdata(1);
echo $username = $user->get('user_login');
```

Но в response ничего не приходит, подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понимаю, то это из WordPress?

Comment: Что то не видно ни таблицы, ни запроса

Comment: Да, Дмитрий, это из вордпресс